# Nodejs naming conventions for modules

Tags: node.js, naming-conventions

Given this pattern :

A module defines a public API, but needs runtime information.

```
// Contrived example for a module abstracting a db
module.exports = function (host, schema, ...) {

  // A "module-level", private, instance of an object
  // that will be used by the public API of the module
  var connection = getConnection(host, schema, ...);

  return {
      queryItems : function (arg) {
          // Something that uses both the "module" level instance
          // and runtime args.
          return connection.query(... arg ... ); 
      }
  }
};
```

Another module will have to require it, than "instanciate" the module, and
use it.

```
// Module "bar"
var db = require("db"),
    xxx = db("myhost", "myschema");

xxx.queryItems("Test"):
```

In "traditionnal" OO, the first module would expose a class constructor, and by conventions those
have a first capital letter, so you would write

```
var Db = require("db"),
    db = new Db("....", "....");
```

And there is not ambiguity ; the meaning of "var cat = new Cat()" is pretty accepted ; "var felix = new Cat()" would only be used in case of multiple instances.

Is there a "canonical" / "idiomatic" way, in nodejs, to name such a module exposing functions, and the object that was returned by this function ?

(Sorry if too subjective, I'm looking for the "established" convention rather than a "best" one.)